# What would make a Google map Ag object returned without mapDataProvider?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

I'm working on an SPA project  (ionic, so it's angular with ui-router) where I need to display two different maps on two different pages/controllers.

The first map is a general map (let's call it the main map)where a few locations are marked and the second one (let's call it the edit map)is a focus on a specific location where the user can edit the location by dragging the marker.

The general implementation scheme I'm using is that I'm calling a initMap method from mappingService that instanciates a google map from each controller.

$rootScope.markers = [];

```
this.initMap = function initMap(mapTarget, mapCenter) {
  // the initMap function initialize the map it takes two arguments:
  //  + mapTaget which defines the html element the map is bound to.
  //  + mapCenter that defines the center of the map and whether to display the center

  var markup = "<div id='" + mapTarget.mapId + "'></div>";
  document.getElementById(mapTarget.containerId).innerHTML = markup;

  var centerPos = new google.maps.LatLng(mapCenter.lat, mapCenter.lng);

  $rootScope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(mapTarget.mapId), {
    center: centerPos,
    zoom: 18,
    disableDefaultUI: true
  });

  // eventually place a person marker for the user's position
  if (mapCenter.display) {
    console.log('placing the position marker');
    $rootScope.markers[0] = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: mapCenter.lat, lng: mapCenter.lng},
      map: $rootScope.map,
      title: 'userLocation',
      icon: './img/person_icon.png'
    });
  }
};
```

The only difference is that on the main map I'm first calling a geolocate service the return a promise and I'm using the returned location coordinates to then call the mapping service:

```
geolocateService.getLocalPosition()
        .then(function(coords) {
          mappingService.initMap(
            {containerId: $scope.mapContainer, mapId: $scope.mapId},
            {lat: coords.lat, lng: coords.lng, display: true}
          );
```

While on the edit map I'm calling directly the mapping service.

```
mappingService.initMap(
  {containerId: $scope.mapContainer, mapId: $scope.mapId},
  {lat: $scope.location.lat, lng: $scope.location.lng, display: false}
);
```

I am able to render both maps without problem and even to add markers and some event listeners.

However, I run into the problem that after some sequence of actions, for example going from the main map to the edit map two times, one of the map would suddenly become blank (white to be exactly, so it doesn't seems to be something that I could solve by resizing the map). I'm receiving the Ag object and the only difference is that I don't get the mapDataProviders property on the broken map.

When it works, I get:

[Ag object when it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzxEQ.png)

While when it doesn't, I get:

[Ag object when it doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Is6aq.png)

The code snippet above is my last implementation attempt. I've been trying to implement those maps from a lot of different ways to no avail. Among those attempts, I tried:

- totally separates both instanciation, dividing the initMap methods into an initMainMap and an initEditMap.
- using one instance for both maps and replacing the DOM element> This is what you see above with the following additional method that is called when leaving the view:

  this.removeMap = function removeMap(containerId) {
    var container = document.getElementById(containerId);
    $rootScope.markers = [];
    container.innerHTML = '';
    // important part:
    var old_element = container;
    var new_element = old_element.cloneNode(true);
    old_element.parentNode.replaceChild(new_element, old_element);

  delete $rootScope.map;
  }

  knowing that on both views I have either:

or

```
<div id="edit-map-container"></div>
```

I'm trying to understand what would make the google map API return a map without mapDataProvider (which I believe means that the map works and even starts to render except that it lacks the tiles to display).

P.S. it looks like there is a memory leak, which is apparently a well known issue.

If anyone has the answer to this, I'm a bit lost right here!

Comment: Actually, one of the first thing I'd like to know is whether this could be a consequence of a memory leak. It looks like I have one although quite small and it might totally be unrelated.